# Selecting/Exporting points from one layer that do not overlap with the points from another layer in Qgis

Tags: qgis, vector, overlapping-features

I am working with QGIS and have the following problem to solve:

I have 2 point layers. Layer 1 has more points than Layer 2 but all points of Layer 2 have the same position as Layer 1. I need to find those points that do not overlap. 
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

First download and install this plugin :[plugin +  official docs in english !](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spatial_query.html)
It is a very useful tool !

If this doesn't work (ie point aren't exactly at the same location), create a buffer around the points and use the same method as above.

You can also use the build in qgis/saga functions using the toolbox

Comment: Thank you! Could have thought about it myself but I haven't really used that plugin much in the past :-)

Answer (score 1):

To suggest a non-plugin solution. Use the difference tool in the vector>geoprocessing menu.

You should add as input layer the layer with more points (Points 2 in image below - green circles); and as difference layer you should use the second layer (Points 1 in image below (stars). Set the output and get the result (triangles in image below).

[image: Tool]

and the result:

[image: Result]